# Объявление структуры через typedef

Tags: qt, c++

```
#ifndef SOCKETTEST_H
#define SOCKETTEST_H

#include <QObject>
#include <QUdpSocket>
#include <QDebug>

typedef unsigned long int ISZ;
typedef unsigned int DWORD;
typedef unsigned char BYTE;
typedef unsigned short WORD;

#pragma pack(1)

// Заголовок всех сообщений
typedef struct
{
    WORD msg_type;          // Тип сообщения                        1-2
    WORD msg_len;           // Длина сообщения                      3-4
    WORD send_id;           // Отправитель                          5-6
    WORD recv_id;           // Получатель                           7-8
    WORD reserv_1;          // Резерв                               9-10
    WORD reserv_2;          // Резерв                               11-12
    WORD reserv_3;          // Резерв                               13-14
    WORD reserv_4;          // Резерв                               15-16
    DWORD u_id;             // Уникальный индификатор               17-20
} _AAHDR;  //? зачем????
```

Сам вопрос, в общем, зачем класс обзывать (_AAHDR) в самом конце? Перерыл много книг, но так и не понял, зачем так делать.

Comment: А где Вы здесь увидели **класс**?

Объявляется безымянная структура, которой используя `typedef` присваивается имя "типа" \_AAHDR.

Далее можно писать что-то вроде

     _AAHDR a;
     a.msg_type = ...

В общем, просто такой подход, маскирующий (от кого и зачем?) реализацию типа, разработчику почему-то понравился.

Comment: видимо, автор этого кода много писал на чистом си. А там этот прием используется повсеместно, так как он позволяет позже писать объявления структур без слова struct. В обычном с++ этого уже не нужно делать.